# Why % Processor Time of W3WP is higher than % Processor Time of the whole processor?

Tags: load, cpu-usage, processor, perfmon, w3wp

I run perfmon on one of the Production Server Machines.
My aim was to monitor the Processor load.

This is the result:
http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3765/lf6.gif

Could you please tell me why "% Processor Time" of the process W3WP is higher than every other "% Processor Time" of the single processors and of the "% Processor Time" total?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **% Processor Time** of a process is calculated on a base line of (100 * number of logical processors).

The Total **% Processor Time** is not.

Nevertheless if **% Processor Time** of a process is greater than (100 * number of logical CPUS) it means that the process is using the processing units to more of their actual capacity.

More on the topic: [Understanding % Processor Time](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-time-and-process-processor-time.aspx)

Comment: The Production Server has 8 physical CPUs (Intel Xeon E5520 @2,27 GHz). Could you please help me understand the picture? http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3765/lf6.gif

Comment: @parentissimo Yes,
the picture loks fine to me if the process is doing something.
So in perfomon you're seeing that the process w3wp is using an average of 42% of your total computing power which in your case is 800% (100 * number of logical processors ) remember?
This said, w3wp is using an average of 5.25% (42/800*100) of total cpu time.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam! It is very halpful for me!

Comment: I cannot because, unfortunatly, I need a minimum reputation of 15 :-(

Comment: Thats fine happy to have helped :P
Cheers.

Comment: Excuse me  Sam, but every CPU of the Production Server (Intel Xeon E5520 @2,27 GHz) is composed by 4 cores. So, are you sure that the logical processors are only 8? If 8 is the number of physical processors and every processor has 4 cores, so the number of logical processors is 32. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct the total number of logical processors is 32.
My bad. So processor time for the process is 42/3200*100.